# Semantic HTML – How to present a comparison of products?

Tags: html

I am about to present a few products on a website in order to allow a customer to choose between them. Each has a name, description and a list of pros and cons compared to the other products. I am unsure about how to structure the HTML.

I see multiple solutions here, headings and paragraphs being the most obvious one, but I wonder if one of the others might be more appropriate. I think the meta-question here is: Is there even a “most correct” solution; and how would one find go about finding it?

## Headings and paragraphs

```
<h2>Product one</h2>
<p>This is our topseller…</p>
<h3>Pros</h3>
<p>…</p>
<h3>Cons</h3>
<p>…</p>

<h2>Product two</h2>
```

## Definition list

Given that I present a number of things with an accompanying description, the definition list might be suitable, since it creates a tighter link between the product name and the information about it.

```
<dl>
    <dt>Product one</dt>
    <dd>
        This is our topseller.
        <h2>Pros</h2><p>…<\p> <!-- Instead of the heading, I also thought of -->
        <h2>Cons</h2><p>…<\p> <!-- using <strong> or no markup at all. -->
    </dd>
    <dt>Product two</dt>
</dl>
```

## Articles or sections

Based on how important the products are in the context of the page, I think an article might be justified, though I’m not quite convinced about this, since the descriptions will be somewhat short – maybe 5–10 sentences.

```
<article>
    <h1>Product one</h1>
    <p>This is our topseller.<p>
    …
</article>
<article>
    <h1>Product two</h1>
    …
</article>
```

Sections might be more appropriate, considering that the whole comparison probably is the “complete, or self-contained, composition” the W3C talks about in [its definiton of HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-article-element), and each product a “thematic grouping” as referenced in the section about [sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sections.html#the-section-element).

## Thematic break

With the re-definition of the hr element to indicate a “paragraph-level thematic break” [[3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element)], the rather short descriptions could also be presented in paragraphs

```
<p>
    <strong>Product one.</strong>
    This is our topseller.
    <strong>Pros:</strong> …
    <strong>Cons:</strong>
</p>
<hr>
<p>
    <strong>Product two.</strong>
    …
</p>
```

Comment: This isn't asked enough, imo. However, I don't think this layout is generic enough to warrant enough semantic elements available in the spec, happy to be proved wrong. Personally, I would wrap your product list in a `<div>` and perhaps each product in a `<section>`, as you mentioned. You can use `<p>`, `<strong>`, and `<h1-6>` for basic  typography. You can also consider elements  like `<summary>` and `<details>`, [as detailed here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element#Interactive_elements). In this case, wouldn't say there's a "most correct" solution, just best judgement.

Comment: The world's largest online retailer (Amazon) uses "horror of horrors" <table> for comparing one product against other similar ones.

Comment: @Neil The “industry standard” unfortunately doesn’t always make a good teacher, especially big, old companies.

Comment: <table> is not an evil tag. So many purists go through weird hoops trying to avoid using them. When used for tabular data they are the best option to use. If I wanted to compare a few products I would do it in tabular form as Amazon(a big, old yet extremely successful) does, each product being a column, the first row being the price then each row being a specification (e.g. what formats an image-processing S/W supports), or option e.g. the type of support and upgrade options. It is fine to use <dl> to describe the products, but to do a comparison IMHO a <table> is usually the right way to go.

Comment: @Neil A table feels inappropriate, since the products are not too similar. I agree that a table is the best solution for things differ in the values of shared categories (like the image formats you mentioned), but in this case these categories would be `name`, `description`, `pros` and `cons`, which i don’t consider “tabular data”. Another point against tables is that—in my experience—one has to go through _awful_ hoops to make them responsive, which is a requirement here.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use definition lists all the way (and nest your pro/con lists as separate DLs):

```html
<dl>
<dt>Product 1</dt>
<dd>Description of Product 1</dd>
<dd>
  <dl>
    <dt>Pros</dt>
    <dd>Pro 1</dd>
    <dd>Pro 2</dd>
    
    <dt>Cons</dt>
    <dd>Con 1</dd>
    <dd>Con 2</dd>
  </dl>
</dd>

<dt>Product 2</dt>
<dd>Description of Product 2</dd>
<dd>
  <dl>
    <dt>Pros</dt>
    <dd>Pro 1</dd>
    <dd>Pro 2</dd>
    
    <dt>Cons</dt>
    <dd>Con 1</dd>
    <dd>Con 2</dd>
  </dl>
</dd>
</dl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most webshops/ecommerce platforms use `ul > li` nodes for displaying lists of products (like Magento 2 and some Wordpress plugins). This however, is a personal choice. Depending on the context of products you can use `article`s, `ul` or `ol` elements. Personally I would advise that if you're providing users with `list-based content`, to always use a `ul` or `ol` element like such:

```
<section class="product-comparison">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <div class="image">
                <img src=""/>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="title">
                    <h2>my product title</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="inner">
                    <p>my description</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        ...
    </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining how in your opinion an unordered list is superior to the other approaches, especially definition lists?